# Subtracting timestamps in sql

Tags: sql, netezza

I have the following two cases

Case1

Table1

```
Name  Start_Sub1           End_Sub1            Start_Sub2           End_Sub2 
A    2018-09-19 07:42:00  2018-09-19 09:12:00 2018-09-23 04:02:00 2018-09-23 05:09:00
```

I want to find the total time the student has spent in the exam, i.e in both the subjects. Which function should I use to get this.

Case 2:
Due to human error, the data has been documented like this:

```
Name  Start_Sub1           End_Sub1            Start_Sub2           End_Sub2 
A    2018-09-19 07:42:00  2018-09-19 09:12:00 2018-09-19 08:02:00 2018-09-19 02:09:00
```

In this case, the time is overlapping in both the timestamps. Can the total time spent in the exam be calculated in such a scenario?

Comment: How would you resolve your Case 2 with paper and pencil?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I am running my queries on Netezza

Comment: Use a `CASE` clause to differentiate between the separated and overlapping cases. Then, just use timestamp difference. Problem solved.

Comment: Can someone tell me the function for Case 1

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the timestamps to seconds using the `EXTRACT()` function and find out if the segments overlap or not. The query should look like:

```
select
  *,
  case 
    when extract(epoch from End_Sub1) < extract(epoch from Start_Sub2) 
    then extract(epoch from End_Sub1) - extract(epoch from Start_Sub1) +
         extract(epoch from End_Sub2) - extract(epoch from Start_Sub2)
    else extract(epoch from End_Sub2) - extract(epoch from Start_Sub1)
  end as diff
from table1
```

For details on how to get the time difference see [Time difference in seconds using Nettezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046954/time-difference-in-seconds-using-netezza).